# Google Map and Display None

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I see others have the same problem and I have tried the google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize'); and other options from this site and no matter what I try I just can't get this to work right.
Here is the code without all the options that I can't get to work. I figured it would be easier to add then to try and fix.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCrL67QeBn59gg63sOW5-u0tAbpH2j7IK4&sensor=false&extension=.js'></script>
<script>
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);
    var map;
    function init() {
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(9.150041177812687, -83.73987379035185),
        zoom: 11,
        zoomControl: true,
        zoomControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.DEFAULT,
        },
        disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
        mapTypeControl: true,
        mapTypeControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR,
        },
        scaleControl: true,
        scrollwheel: true,
        panControl: true,
        streetViewControl: true,
        draggable : true,
        overviewMapControl: true,
        overviewMapControlOptions: {
            opened: false,
        },
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        styles: [{"featureType":"administrative.land_parcel","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"landscape.man_made","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"poi","elementType":"labels","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"labels","stylers":[{"visibility":"simplified"},{"lightness":20}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"hue":"#f49935"}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"labels","stylers":[{"visibility":"simplified"}]},{"featureType":"road.arterial","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"hue":"#fad959"}]},{"featureType":"road.arterial","elementType":"labels","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"road.local","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"visibility":"simplified"}]},{"featureType":"road.local","elementType":"labels","stylers":[{"visibility":"simplified"}]},{"featureType":"transit","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"water","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"hue":"#a1cdfc"},{"saturation":30},{"lightness":49}]}],
    }
    var mapElement = document.getElementById('Cities');
    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, mapOptions);
    var locations = [
        ['San Jose', 'undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined', 9.922489357888226, -84.09076751534423, 'http://thecostaricatoursite.com/images/maps/San-Jose.png'],
        ['CORCOVADO', 'undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined', 8.513076238639655, -83.63826823411557, 'http://thecostaricatoursite.com/images/maps/CORCOVADO.png'],
        ['Uvia', 'undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined', 9.150041177812687, -83.73987379035185, 'http://thecostaricatoursite.com/images/maps/DOMINICAL-UVITA.png'],
        ['Arenal', 'undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined', 10.439814447913703, -84.66606394726563, 'http://thecostaricatoursite.com/images/maps/Arenal.png'],
        ['Jaco', 'undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined', 9.620213,  -84.622485, 'http://thecostaricatoursite.com/images/maps/JACO.png'],
        ['MANUEL-ANTONIO', 'undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined', 9.401996232338849, -84.15583516931156, 'http://thecostaricatoursite.com/images/maps/MANUEL-ANTONIO.png'],
        ['MONTEVERDE', 'undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined', 10.26169695130501, -84.82557165606693, 'http://thecostaricatoursite.com/images/maps/MONTEVERDE.png'],
        ['PAPAGAYO', 'undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined', 10.550227,  -85.697340, 'http://thecostaricatoursite.com/images/maps/PAPAGAYO.png'],
        ['PUERTO VIEJO', 'undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined', 9.657154,  -82.756974, 'http://thecostaricatoursite.com/images/maps/PUERTO-VIEJO.png'],
        ['TAMARINDO', 'undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined', 10.296203852400582, -85.84199989947513, 'http://thecostaricatoursite.com/images/maps/TAMARINDO.png'],
        ['TORTUGUERO', 'undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined', 10.538444882330598, -83.50339050793457, 'http://thecostaricatoursite.com/images/maps/TORTUGUERO.png']
    ];
    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        if (locations[i][1] =='undefined'){ description ='';} else { description = locations[i][1];}
        if (locations[i][2] =='undefined'){ telephone ='';} else { telephone = locations[i][2];}
        if (locations[i][3] =='undefined'){ email ='';} else { email = locations[i][3];}
       if (locations[i][4] =='undefined'){ web ='';} else { web = locations[i][4];}
       if (locations[i][7] =='undefined'){ markericon ='';} else { markericon = locations[i][7];}
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            icon: markericon,
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][5], locations[i][6]),
            map: map,
            title: locations[i][0],
            desc: description,
            tel: telephone,
            email: email,
            web: web
        });
        link = '';     }
        }
</script>
<style>
#Cities {
    height:500px;
    width:100%;
}
.gm-style-iw * {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
.gm-style-iw h4, .gm-style-iw p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.gm-style-iw a {
    color: #4272db;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="col-sm-2">
    <input name="More Info" type="button" class="details-css" id="Map" value="View map of Dominical / Uvita" />
                        <script>
                            $('#Map').click(function() {
                            $('#Map-1').toggle('swing', function() {
                                });
                                });
                        </script>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 More-Info" id="Map-1" style="display:none;">       
         <div id="Cities"></div>
    </div
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for any help on getting this to work right.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the map as a global variable, remove var here:

```
map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, mapOptions);
```

Here is working fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/9mfjt5uq/1/

Comment: Just tied this and does not work and it breaks the button so it only opens the div but then will not close the div

Comment: found the issue, posting jsfiddle

Comment: Works great, Thank you so very very much

Comment: Awesome! Good luck with project.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple problems.

1. You need to call `google.maps.event.trigger(map,'resize')` after the animation completes.

   $('#Map-1').toggle('swing', function() {
     google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize')
   }

(as Goran Jakovljevic suggested in his original answer, now overwritten)

2. You need the map variable to be in scope when you call `google.maps.event.trigger(map,'resize')`.
3. You need to initialize the button onclick listener after the DOM is rendered (your code does this, but does it inline).

One option is to move the button click initialization inside your `init` function (where it is in the local scope).

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/347v7k4p/)

**code snippet:**

```js
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);
var map;

function init() {
  var mapElement = document.getElementById('Cities');
  map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, mapOptions);
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    if (locations[i][1] == 'undefined') {
      description = '';
    } else {
      description = locations[i][1];
    }
    if (locations[i][2] == 'undefined') {
      telephone = '';
    } else {
      telephone = locations[i][2];
    }
    if (locations[i][3] == 'undefined') {
      email = '';
    } else {
      email = locations[i][3];
    }
    if (locations[i][4] == 'undefined') {
      web = '';
    } else {
      web = locations[i][4];
    }
    if (locations[i][7] == 'undefined') {
      markericon = '';
    } else {
      markericon = locations[i][7];
    }
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      // icon: markericon,
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][5], locations[i][6]),
      map: map,
      title: locations[i][0],
      desc: description,
      tel: telephone,
      email: email,
      web: web
    });
    link = '';
    bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
  }
  $('#Map').click(function() {
    $('#Map-1').toggle('swing', function() {
      google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize')
      map.fitBounds(bounds);
    });
  });

}
var mapOptions = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(9.150041177812687, -83.73987379035185),
  zoom: 11,
  zoomControl: true,
  zoomControlOptions: {
    style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.DEFAULT,
  },
  disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
  mapTypeControl: true,
  mapTypeControlOptions: {
    style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR,
  },
  scaleControl: true,
  scrollwheel: true,
  panControl: true,
  streetViewControl: true,
  draggable: true,
  overviewMapControl: true,
  overviewMapControlOptions: {
    opened: false,
  },
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  styles: [{
    "featureType": "administrative.land_parcel",
    "elementType": "all",
    "stylers": [{
      "visibility": "off"
    }]
  }, {
    "featureType": "landscape.man_made",
    "elementType": "all",
    "stylers": [{
      "visibility": "off"
    }]
  }, {
    "featureType": "poi",
    "elementType": "labels",
    "stylers": [{
      "visibility": "off"
    }]
  }, {
    "featureType": "road",
    "elementType": "labels",
    "stylers": [{
      "visibility": "simplified"
    }, {
      "lightness": 20
    }]
  }, {
    "featureType": "road.highway",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [{
      "hue": "#f49935"
    }]
  }, {
    "featureType": "road.highway",
    "elementType": "labels",
    "stylers": [{
      "visibility": "simplified"
    }]
  }, {
    "featureType": "road.arterial",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [{
      "hue": "#fad959"
    }]
  }, {
    "featureType": "road.arterial",
    "elementType": "labels",
    "stylers": [{
      "visibility": "off"
    }]
  }, {
    "featureType": "road.local",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [{
      "visibility": "simplified"
    }]
  }, {
    "featureType": "road.local",
    "elementType": "labels",
    "stylers": [{
      "visibility": "simplified"
    }]
  }, {
    "featureType": "transit",
    "elementType": "all",
    "stylers": [{
      "visibility": "off"
    }]
  }, {
    "featureType": "water",
    "elementType": "all",
    "stylers": [{
      "hue": "#a1cdfc"
    }, {
      "saturation": 30
    }, {
      "lightness": 49
    }]
  }],
}
var locations = [
  ['San Jose', 'undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined', 9.922489357888226, -84.09076751534423, 'http://thecostaricatoursite.com/images/maps/San-Jose.png'],
  ['CORCOVADO', 'undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined', 8.513076238639655, -83.63826823411557, 'http://thecostaricatoursite.com/images/maps/CORCOVADO.png'],
  ['Uvia', 'undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined', 9.150041177812687, -83.73987379035185, 'http://thecostaricatoursite.com/images/maps/DOMINICAL-UVITA.png'],
  ['Arenal', 'undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined', 10.439814447913703, -84.66606394726563, 'http://thecostaricatoursite.com/images/maps/Arenal.png'],
  ['Jaco', 'undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined', 9.620213, -84.622485, 'http://thecostaricatoursite.com/images/maps/JACO.png'],
  ['MANUEL-ANTONIO', 'undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined', 9.401996232338849, -84.15583516931156, 'http://thecostaricatoursite.com/images/maps/MANUEL-ANTONIO.png'],
  ['MONTEVERDE', 'undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined', 10.26169695130501, -84.82557165606693, 'http://thecostaricatoursite.com/images/maps/MONTEVERDE.png'],
  ['PAPAGAYO', 'undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined', 10.550227, -85.697340, 'http://thecostaricatoursite.com/images/maps/PAPAGAYO.png'],
  ['PUERTO VIEJO', 'undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined', 9.657154, -82.756974, 'http://thecostaricatoursite.com/images/maps/PUERTO-VIEJO.png'],
  ['TAMARINDO', 'undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined', 10.296203852400582, -85.84199989947513, 'http://thecostaricatoursite.com/images/maps/TAMARINDO.png'],
  ['TORTUGUERO', 'undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined', 10.538444882330598, -83.50339050793457, 'http://thecostaricatoursite.com/images/maps/TORTUGUERO.png']
];
```

```css
#Cities {
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
}
.gm-style-iw * {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
.gm-style-iw h4,
.gm-style-iw p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.gm-style-iw a {
  color: #4272db;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-2">
  <input name="More Info" type="button" class="details-css" id="Map" value="View map of Dominical / Uvita" />
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div class="col-sm-12 More-Info" id="Map-1" style="display:none;">
  <div id="Cities"></div>
</div>
```